# Codemagic pre-build Issue for Firebase config

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, codemagic

There's a codemagic guide that shows how to use `google-services.json` and `GoogleService-Info.plist` without committing them to the main repo:

https://docs.codemagic.io/custom-scripts/load-firebase-configuration/

I've renamed the variables used, but otherwise followed the steps exactly for my project. The pre-build script shows this error:

```
/var/folders/r7/d9twdq011sb8d3q1p8f39cdr0000gn/T/build_script_3_0_ef_shxdc: line 5: /Users/builder/clone/android/app/google-services.json: No such file or directory
```

The "No such file or directory" makes me wonder if the `$FCI_BUILD_DIR` variable isn't right?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows that your `$FCI_BUILD_DIR` is expanded correctly.
First thing you can do is make sure the parent directory exists.

if not you can just add this:
`mkdir -p $FCI_BUILD_DIR/android/app` before the `echo..` part. and if needed the same with `/ios/Runner`

or if your project exists within a subdirectory then you will need to reflect the directory structure in your pre-build script.

Comment: Thanks @rimante-valancauskaite - my project lives within a subdirectory, so the cp command must reflect that. Hence the error!